# Change file contents in memory, before writing to disk

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

I'm using Grunt to build a project. D'oh.
One of the things I need to do is change some vars (API endpoints) in a configuration file.
I only do that in the dist folder and currently copy the file, then edit its contents.

Now, is it possible to edit file contents before copying, so in memory?
If Grunt cannot do that, can Gulp?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about grunt, but it's pretty easy in gulp since everything is based on streams. For example, if you just need regex replace, you can use the [`gulp-replace`](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace) module.

Comment: Grunt has grunt-replace too (or such), but it requires a file location where to make the edits. It can't make it in memory before writing the actual file.